# System.TypeException: Invalid id value for this SObject type: 00e340000015Qg3AAE

Tags: apex, id, portal, invalid

I've run into a problem a trigger I'm trying to implement.  The trigger is supposed to fire when a User is updated.  It then has a conditional to check if the user's profile was updated to a specific value, and if so, sends an email alerting that user to the change.  The profile I am checking for is named "Community Customer - On Hold"

I've run into several errors, but recently the trigger isn't even firing.  I get the error

> System.TypeException: Invalid id value for this SObject type: 00e340000015Qg3AAE

I've been working on this for quite some time now, and figured I should probably reach out for some help.  Any help is much appreciated!

Here is my TRIGGER:

```
trigger UserOnHoldTrigger on User (after update) {
    //Creates an array to hold the users caused by trigger firing
    user[] usersList = trigger.new;
    for(user x : usersList){
        String userProfile = x.profileID;
        if(userProfile.endsWith('Hold')){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String emailAddress = [SELECT Email
                                   FROM User
                                   WHERE ID = :usersList].email;
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {emailAddress};
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            mail.setSubject('Community User Account Placed on Hold');
            Mail.setPlainTextBody('Your Community User account has been placed on hold.');
            messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail}); 
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my TEST CLASS:

```
@isTest
public class UserOnHoldTriggerTest {
    @isTest private static void testInsert(){

        Contact contactToInsert = new Contact();
        contactToInsert.FirstName = 'Test';
        contactToInsert.Lastname = 'Contact';
        contactToInsert.Id = [SELECT id FROM profile where Name = 'Customer Community - On Hold'].Id;
        insert contactToInsert;

        User userToInsert = new User();
        userToInsert.FirstName = 'Mike';
        userToInsert.LastName = 'Smith';
        userToInsert.email = 'msmith@company.com';
        userToInsert.Alias = 'alias';
        userToInsert.Username = 'msith@company.com';
        userToInsert.CommunityNickname = 'commnick';
        userToInsert.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
        userToInsert.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Denver';
        userToInsert.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        userToInsert.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
        userToInsert.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        userToInsert.street = 'street drive';
        userToInsert.City = 'cityville';
        userToInsert.State = 'New York';
        userToInsert.PostalCode = '30000';
        userToInsert.Country = 'USA';
        userToInsert.ProfileId = contactToInsert.id;
        update userToInsert;
    }
}
```

This may or may not be helpful, but before I updated my Test Class, I was getting the error:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Cannot create a portal user without contact: [ContactId]

I think I simply added the contact ID in the test class to fix that.  Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test class.

You can't assign Id to any sobject. Id generates after insert operation happens.

So you need to remove below line.

```
contactToInsert.Id = [SELECT id FROM profile 
                      where Name = 'Customer Community - On Hold'].Id;
```

And store profile Id in another variable

```
Id profId = [SELECT id FROM profile 
                          where Name = 'Customer Community - On Hold'].Id;
```

And while inserting user profile Id will be `profId`

```
userToInsert.ProfileId = profId ;
```

And User `ContactId` will be newly created contact Id

```
userToInsert.ContactId = contactToInsert.id;
```

FYI: you can't Update `ContactId`. you can assign this value while creation of user record

Comment: That fixed the error, thank you!
I'm of course met another error, this one is 

"System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, portal account owner must have a role: []"

So I'm working on that.  I'm finding I can't hard code those values in, such as "userToInsert.UserRoleID= "Customer";

So I'm guessing I need to do another Query for that.

Comment: @DanielSassone this error means when you create a contact for user before that you need one Account and associate that Account with user's contact. So basically your Account's owner(i.e. user object) should have any role..

Comment: @DanielSassone Can you create a new thread and add your code there what you have tried so far..

Comment: Add an answer to my own question?  or ask a new question?

Comment: @DanielSassone ask a new question.. I will take a look

Comment: Link to the new question.
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117240/follow-up-error-insert-failed-portal-account-owner-must-have-a-role
Thanks!